# Moving tree in table to top of row

Tags: tables, tikz-qtree

I have a table with 4 trees in them as shown below.

I want the tree in the fourth column to be moved up matching the other trees in terms of distance from the top.

[image]

My MWE is given below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[shortlabels, inline]{enumitem}

\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0ptm, nolistsep, nosep}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!]
\small
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
descendant & ancestor & (g)\_nibling & sibling
\\
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\Tree [.person [.... [.adjective ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\Tree [.adjective [.... [.person ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\Tree [.parent [.... [.adjective ] ] [.person ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\Tree [.parent [.adjective ] [.person ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be selecting a similar `baseline` for all `tikzpictures`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[shortlabels, inline]{enumitem}

\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0ptm, nolistsep, nosep}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!]
\small
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
descendant & ancestor & (g)\_nibling & sibling
\\
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=.8]
\Tree [.person [.... [.adjective ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=.8]
\Tree [.adjective [.... [.person ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),scale=.8]
\Tree [.parent [.... [.adjective ] ] [.person ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north), scale=.8]
\Tree [.parent [.adjective ] [.person ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

For this case where every top node has different height and depth, could be better to use the baseline of top nodes as reference. But this case implies to change `.label` syntax to `.\node(name){label};`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[shortlabels, inline]{enumitem}

\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0ptm, nolistsep, nosep}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!]
\small
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
descendant & ancestor & (g)\_nibling & sibling
\\
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(top.base), scale=.8]
\Tree [.\node(top){person}; [.... [.adjective ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(top.base), scale=.8]
\Tree [.\node(top){adjective}; [.... [.person ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(top.base), scale=.8]
\Tree [.\node(top){parent}; [.... [.adjective ] ] [.person ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(top.base), scale=.8]
\Tree [.\node(top){parent}; [.adjective ] [.person ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]